# How to parse json in react native

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on react native project, and i'm calling API and extracting data from it , the data is succesfully extracted but I want to take arguments from the extracted data and I did'nt know how
This is the code for fetching api :

```
Axios({
url: '/Authentification',
method: 'get',
baseURL: 'http://smart.netrostercloud.com/api',
transformRequest: [
  function (data, headers) {
    return data;
  },
],
transformResponse: [
  function (data) {
    // console.log(data);
    setData3(data);
  },
],
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Basic UxvwJc1GWjkOCyZoIHGuCD05gDUB72sqrgK30FgILho=',
},


});

  console.log(data3);
```

I've used data3 to extract the data in my main function so it can be visible.
This is the data :
[image]

I want to take CompanyCode,UserName,Password,FirstName and LastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you storing data into data3 you need to stringify the data like this `setData3(JSON.stringify(data));`

and then try this:

```
if (data3) {
  const COMP_NAME = data?.user?.CompanyCode;
  const USER_NAME = data?.user?.UserName;
  CONST FIRST_NAME = data?.user?.FirstName;
  CONST LAST_NAME = data?.user?.LastName;
}
```

Comment: it render me an error :  ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data3.user.CompanyCode')

Comment: updated my answer please do a console of `data3` and `data3.user` if any error occurs

Comment: see i'm putting this :const COMP_NAME = data3.user.CompanyCode;
  const USER_NAME = data3.user.UserName;
  console.log(USER_NAME);               I had same error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data3.user.CompanyCode')

Comment: Make sure data3 contains come values.. I have updated my answer please check

Comment: yeah it contains , I'll do this code after Axios ... right ?

Comment: Yes after you getting the response from axios

Answer (score 1):

Firstly : axios its n asynchronous function, so its return a promise,
Actually i dont prefere use this patern in simple api call l, but its good way if you know this concept and use oop like create instance of axios to reusable and cancel connectiin when component will unmount.

```cs
Fot this i prefere use this way
Const getUserData= async () =>{
try {
Const {data} = await axios.get(baseurl+route, headers , options) 
data & & SetData({username:data. User. Username,........... } )
Dosomthing... 
}
Catch(error) {
Dosomthing... 
}
```